# MediaPlayer on a Service causing an IllegalStateException and the app crashes

Tags: android, service, android-mediaplayer, android-dialogfragment

I am trying to implement my MediaPlayer in a Service, and so far everything was working fine.
However, there's one scenario in which my app crashes.

Here's the scenario:

- I search for an artist, and a list with the results is displayed
- I select a an artist, and the artist's top tracks are displayed (on a different Activity)
- I click on a track, my DialogFragment opens, my Service is started, and the song starts to play
- I press the back button, and the DialogFragment is destroyed. The song is still playing.
- I press the back button again, which takes me back to the artist's results screen. Song stops playing.
- I selected another (or the same) artist. The new screen is displayed with the top tracks.
- When I click on a track, it SHOULD do what did before - open the DialogFragment and play the song, however, the app crashes.

My log says it was caused bu an IllegalStateException when I try to call any method on my MediaPlayer instance within my Service.

That leads me to believe that the Service lost the reference to the MediaPlayer?

This is the method on my DialogFragment that will retrieve the service after connecting to it, and then call PlayTrack() on my Service, which first resets the player (here's where the exception happenes) and then play the song.

```
private ServiceConnection mediaPlayerConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        MusicBinder binder = (MusicBinder) service;
        mMediaPlayerService = binder.getService();
        mMediaPlayerService.setPlayList(mTracks);
        mMediaPlayerService.setCurrentSong(currentTrack);
        updateMediaPlayerViews();
        mMediaPlayerService.playTrack();
        isMediaPlayerBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        isMediaPlayerBound = false;
    }
};
```

If you need any other part of my code, please let me know.

Any help would be extremely appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the issue.

On my onUnbind method, I call .release() on my media player. Later on, when I Bind to my service again and try to play a new song, I cannot call .reset() on my media player because that is not valid on the player's current state.

You can only call .reset() when your player is on an "active" state, aka after .start() has been called.